# progress bar within a table in pyqt4

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtablewidget, qprogressbar

How could I use PyQt to add a progress bar as a cell in my `TableView`? For example, suppose I have a table that holds several running tasks and I would like one of the cells in each row to show the percentage of the completed  task. [Here is a quick example](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cellrenderers.html#id5) of what I mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from QT documentation Qtable implements QAstractItemView that has the method setIndexWidget(index, new widget()) that you can use to add the qprogressbar

```
tableView.setIndexWidget(index, QProgressBar())
```

Comment: Hello thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question, best regards. :)

Comment: My pleasure and happy hacking